# XSLT tranform in xmlsignature form, a part of xmldocument?

Tags: xml-encryption

I have a HTML page(A Form) where user will enter his details. Details to enter are 
Name
age
salary
state
City
 Now when user enters all details and click **Button** then I will create xml file containing the user details like

```
<root>
<name>abc</name>
<age>40</age>
<salary>20000</age>
<state>xyz</state>
<city>abc</city>
</root>
```

After this I want to sign this xml file using *XMLSignature*. I want to sign only two elements of document i.e name and salary element **using XSLT transform** and some digest and signature method.

My question is how to use the XSLT transform in our xmlsignature's transform element. What is the best way to achieve this?

One more issue when the user presses **Another Button in HTML page**, He should be shown the elements which are signed i.e name and salary should be displayed to user. How can I achieve that. Will XSLT transform plays a role here also?

**Note**: *I am using Java libraries for XMLSignature*
**Note 2**: *I have asked same question in stackoverflow site. Here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680590/xslt-tranform-in-xmlsignature-form-a-part-of-xmldocument*. If i get answer i will remove that.